# how can I make rewrite module in apache works?

Tags: apache, lamp

The rewrite mod for apache is not working on a vps server LAMP (ubuntu 18.04)

What I did:

1) Install apache2, php-7.2 and mysql then configured a virtual host for apache (created a file: /etc/sites-available/example.com.conf) - where example.com is my domain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined   
</VirtualHost>
```

2) Enable the curent virtual host:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
```

3) Disable the default:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

4) Activate Mod_Rewrites

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

5) Add the  config in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

6) Restart the server

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

The main page works, but if I click on a link for example.com/product-page-1 it says:

```
The requested URL /product-page-1 was not found on this server.
```

What I am doing wrong???

**UPDATE**

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# some redirects
Redirect 301 /create-account.html /register
...

</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have 25 - 30 301 redirects in htaccess and if I don`t remove them the server fails

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

If i look in the error log for appache2 i see this:

```
/var/www/example.com/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Register', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

What module needs apache for 301 redirect to work???

Comment: Is there a directory `/product-page-1` under your `DocumentRoot` directory?  Looks like there is not.  As for rewrite, you do not have any rewrite directives in the configuration you showed here.  But as a general answer, make sure you load the module in httpd.conf, and start the engine in your VirtualHost (`RewriteEngine On`).

Comment: There is no directory. It's a laravel project and  the routes should work. On my locahost machine the project is working with the same config

Comment: if looking in error log: `/var/www/example.com/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Register'`

Comment: ok, but in what you showed here, there are no redirections.  Its missing something?

Comment: i have updated the question. If remove the redirects from htaccess now is working. Why the redirects 301 is trowing error in log that: `invalid command register`